# Anonymous contact form

Tags: php, iphone, contacts, anonymous, feedback

I'm making an iPhone 6.0 app that allows a user to send a message to a preset email address but the sender is anonymised. The purpose is for users to be able to ask questions (including stupid ones) without worrying about being thought of as being stupid, therefore, having them sent anonymously.

Does anyone know about the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Layth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signup for a free PHP host and setup a form that accepts messages and forwards them to your email.

On your app present a screen that can be filled and sent to your php form.

Comment: Will that also be anonymous? What if the person has no signal when they send it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use something like https://fncontact.com which lets you make anonymous contact forms.